# Enabling HTTP/2 on the plain text connector

Tags: java-8, jetty, okhttp, http2, apache-httpclient-5.x

Following Jetty documentation of enabling HTTP/2,

I reached till the following step,

> 2015-06-17 14:16:12.549:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@6f32cd1e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8080}

From the docs,

> No major browser currently supports plain text HTTP/2, so the 8080
>   port will only be able to use HTTP/2 with **specific clients** (eg curl)
>   that use the upgrade mechanism or assume HTTP/2.

The documentation mentions **"specific clients"**, but what client I can use for overcoming this issue? I tried `okHttp` and `apache-httpclient`, `okHttp` doesn't support the upgrade mechanism (AFAIK, Would be great if it is otherwise), and `apache-httpClient` doesn't support `h2`.

I basically need to make GET/POST request from my program to this endpoint(Obviously, using HTTP/2).

To put in a simple words, Please suggest any Java client which support non-encrypted http/2 (h2c)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you nee to support HTTP/1 on this port also?

Comment: Yes...to support other services using the same endpoints

Comment: The feature in your client to support non-encrypted http/2 is called `h2c`, look for that.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I am unable to find such a client for Java. Thats the purpose of this question. You paraphrased my question in a better way

Comment: > apache-httpClient doesn't support h2: this statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Apache HttpCore and HttpClient 5.0 support `h2` as well as `h2c` but presently do not support the `http/1.1` to `h2c` upgrade mechanism. I am not sure they ever will given it is unclear how useful this upgrade mechanism is in the first place.

For code examples please refer to

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/examples-async.html

For HttpClient 4.5.x to HttpClient 5.0 upgrade guide please refer to:

https://ok2c.github.io/httpclient-migration-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty Project has a HTTP client library that can be used as HTTP client and supports HTTP/2, both clear text and encrypted.

You want to look at [this](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.20.v20190813/http-client-transport.html#_http_2_transport) documentation.

See also how the Jetty Project uses that same client for [tests](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.20.v20190813/jetty-alpn/jetty-alpn-conscrypt-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/conscrypt/server/ConscryptHTTP2ServerTest.java#L135).